# wprintf UTF16 (should be UTF8) on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, console, wchar-t, wchar

1 It's really strange that wprintf show 'Ω' as 3A9 (UTF16), but wctomb convert
wchar to CEA9 (UTF8), my locale is default en_US.utf8. As man-pages said,
they should comform to my locale, but wpritnf use UTF16, why?

excerpt from http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3a9/index.htm

Ω in UTF

UTF-8 (hex) 0xCE 0xA9 (cea9)

UTF-16 (hex)    0x03A9 (03a9)

2 wprintf and printf just cannot be run in the same program, I have
to choose to use either wprintf or printf, why?

---

See my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
  setlocale(LC_ALL,""); // inherit locale setting from environment
  int r;
  char wc_char[4] = {0,0,0,0};
  wchar_t myChar1 = L'Ω'; //greek 

  // should comment out either wprintf or printf, they don't run together
  r = wprintf(L"char is %lc (%x)\n", myChar1, myChar1);//On Linux, to UTF16

  r = wctomb(wc_char, myChar1); // On Linux, to UTF8
  r = printf("r:%d, %x, %x, %x, %x\n", r, wc_char[0], wc_char[1], wc_char[2], wc_char[3]);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but I can tell you UTF-16 is never used in `char` or `wchar_t` on Linux. (And it can't be used on any conformant C implementation.)

Comment: If you run program, wprintf ("%x", myChar1); prints 3a9(Ω in UTF16) but not cea9(Ω in UTF8)

Comment: From what I know `wchar_t` is 32-bits in Linux. So as R.. said, it isn't UTF-16. I think the locale only affects the non-wide character functions. (some please correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: @Mysticial: Other way around. The non-wide functions are purely byte copying, except for `%ls` and `%lc` with `printf` and `scanf`. The wide functions convert all the wide characters they output to the locale's encoding.

Comment: @R..: Thanks, that's good to know. (I obviously don't change my locale very often... XD)

Comment: If you want to know why `printf()` and `wprintf()` can't be tun together, please read my answer in another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17700797/printf-wprintf-s-s-ls-char-and-wchar-errors-not-announced-by-a-compil#answer-60087756

Answer (score 6):

The answer to your second question has to do with [stream orientation](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Streams-and-I18N.html). You cannot mix `printf()` and `wprintf()` because they require different orientations.

When the process starts, the streams are not set yet. On the first call to a function that uses the stream, it gets set accordingly. `printf()` will set the orientation to normal, and `wprintf()` will set it to wide.

It is undefined behavior to call a function that requires a different orientation as the current setting.

Comment: OP has a comment that one or the other should be commented. I think this is not the issue, but the question is not clearly worded...

Comment: @R..: I noticed that too, though the OP is asking why that's the case. But anyways, I agree, the question is a little unclear - I had to read it several times to get the gist of it.

Comment: Sorry, I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: @user5652: No worries. We won't hold it against you.

Answer (score 2):

How exactly are you determining what the `wprintf` line is printing?  Your comment below the question seems to imply that you're just examining the results of `wprintf ("%x", myChar1);`, which prints the internal numeric value of `myChar1` regardless of character encoding (but not regardless of character set — there's a difference); assuming that your compiler uses Unicode for `wchar_t`s internally (a pretty safe bet, I believe), this simply prints out the Unicode codepoint for 'Ω', which is 0x3a9, independently of UTF-16 vs. UTF-8 distinctions.  In order to tell whether `wprintf` is printing UTF-16, you have to directly examine the raw bytes that are output (e.g., with `hexdump(1)`).  For example, on my computer, the `wprintf` line prints the following:

```
63 68 61 72 20 69 73 20 ce a9 20 28 33 61 39 29 0a
c  h  a  r     i  s     Ω        (  3  a  9  )  \n
```

Note that the omega is encoded in UTF-8 as the bytes CE A9, but the numeric value of the `wchar_t` is still 3A9.

Comment: Are there some sort of environment variables involved?  When I try it on my ubuntu system the output is 'char is ? (3a9)'. It looks like wprintf converted the omega to a question mark because it was unaware that I was on a terminal that could display utf-8. I even set LC_CTYPE to en_US.UTF-8 and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I may have found it.  You need to execute

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "")
```

first.  It looks like the wchar I/O functions are not honoring the LC_ environment variables.

See http://littletux.homelinux.org/knowhow.php?article=charsets/ar01s08 for more background.