# Why can't it print out the character encoded in Shift-JIS?

Tags: c, mingw32, widechar, shift-jis

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main (void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ja_JP.Shift_JIS");
    char Str[3] = {0x82,0xCC,'\0'};
    printf ("(%ls)\n", Str);        // --> A
    wprintf (L"(%ls) \n", Str);     // --> B
    system ("pause");
}
```

**Note** : の = (Shift-JIS) 0x82 0xCC

It printed out so weird: (JUST THREE CHARACTERS and \n was totally ignored!!)

```
(()
```

Why can neither A nor B print out the character encoded in Shift-JIS?

Comment: what is it printing out? garbage? 0x82 and 0xCC as two separate chars?

Comment: What happens when you exchnage to to `*printf()` lines?

Comment: `wchar_t Str[3] = {0x82,0xCC,'\0'};` ?

Comment: Your format string is wrong. `%ls` requires a `wchar_t*`, not a `char*`. Use plain `%s`.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17700797/printf-wprintf-s-s-ls-char-and-wchar-errors-not-announced-by-a-compil for similar issues.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: no. One wchar_t is usually one character (sometimes two, but only for some Unicode characters and not for JIS).

Comment: @n.m `wchar_t Str[] = {...}` better? and talk about Shift-JIS?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY If you need to print one character, your `wchar_t` array should normally contain one element (not including terminating 0). Yours contain two.

Comment: @n.m I do not know what you are saying, sorry.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I don't know how to say it more clearly, sorry.