# Why buffer is getting garbage value?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, garbage, widestring

This code from my project. I am not able to understand from where `buffer` is getting this (**潓敭慮敭(10):**) garbage value after using with `swprintf_s`.

```
    const char* m_filename = "Somename";
    unsigned m_line = 10;
    wchar_t buffer[256];

    ZeroMemory(buffer, 256);

    auto count = swprintf_s(buffer, L"%S(%d): ",
        m_filename, m_line);
```

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Preview.

Comment: That's not garbage. It's Chinese.

Comment: `%S` (i.e., an upper-case `S` in the conversion) tells it to treat the input as wide characters, so it's taking pairs of characters and treating each pair as UTF-16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

swprintf_s expects **wchar_t** string as **'%S'** argument and you are passing **char** string, thus **treating two chars as single wchar_t** (i.e.: 'So' -> '潓').

Comment: With `wprintf`, %s means a wide string and %S means a narrow string. See [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx). Is this behaviour different between `wprintf` and `swprintf_s`?

Comment: It shouldn't. I wouldn't trust MS docs so much though, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17700797/printf-wprintf-s-s-ls-char-and-wchar-errors-not-announced-by-a-compil